# How to solve this error in python ?FileNotFoundError:[WinError 3 The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python-3.x

[image]this is the code

import os

import shutil

shutil.rmtree ("C:\Hayavadan\OneDrive\Python\1 -08-2020")

this is the error i am getting

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Hayavadan/OneDrive/Python/delete by hayuu.py", line 3, in 
shutil.rmtree ("C:\Hayavadan\OneDrive\Python\1 -08-2020")

File "C:\Users\Hayavadan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 737, in rmtree
return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)

File "C:\Users\Hayavadan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 596, in _rmtree_unsafe
onerror(os.scandir, path, sys.exc_info())

File "C:\Users\Hayavadan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 593, in _rmtree_unsafe
with os.scandir(path) as scandir_it:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Hayavadan\OneDrive\Python\1 -08-2020'

Comment: Are you sure filename is correct?

Comment: yes my filename is correct i can also share the image , i have attache the image pls help me solve this error

Answer (score 0):

Do check your environment setup ..